# Access model's view in Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

How can I access View's element that related to Model's object?

For example, I have a collection of `Products`. Each product has `color` property. I'd like to "hide" (i.e. remove View representation) every product whose `color` equals to `"red"`.

The only way I know so far is through invoking (for examle) `destroy()` method of Model's object (the code below). But I don't want to destroy Model's object. Is it possible to remove View's element without changing its Model?

```
// App
hide_red_products: function() { 
  Product.each(function(x) {
    if (x.attributes.color == "red") { x.destroy() }
  })
}


// Products' view
initialize: function() {
  this.model.bind('destroy', this.remove_element, this);
}

remove_element: function() {
  return $(this.el).remove();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model should not control what the view is doing.

You should use the `trigger` method to trigger an event.  Assuming the color changes from some color to red, you should use the `change` event. If you listen to the change event, you shouldn't even need the `hide_red_products` method.

```
// App
hide_red_products: function() { 
  Product.each(function(x) {

    //if (x.attributes.color == "red") { x.trigger() }
    // you should never access a models attributes using the attributes key
    if (x.get('color') === 'red') { x.trigger('change'); } // shouldn't actually need this.
  })
}


// Products' view
initialize: function() {
  //this.model.bind('destroy', this.remove_element, this);
  this.model.bind('change', this.remove_element, this);
}

remove_element: function(model) {
  if (model.get('color') === 'red') {
     $(this.el).remove();
  }
}
```

Like I said earlier, you shouldn't have to call a method to remove the element if the view listens to change events.  If you feel it's necessary you can trigger it yourself using `change` or a custom event `x.trigger('changedToRed');`

Comment: Beat me by a couple minutes. I whipped up a quick'n'dirty (and contrived) demo if you want it: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Ex8KJ/1/

Comment: Thank yous very much for the answer and demo app, very useful!